# Excel: Index Match with partial text search into another Worksheet

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, partial

Attempting to use a Index* + Match* + Match partial* function from one Workbook to another Workbook.

This formula works within the same workbook, but fails once applied over to another Workbook.

- Retrieving Workbook: Ship Log
- Retrieving Sheet: 2023
- Index search column: F:F
- First Match column: H:H   --    matching with cell: W2
- Partial Match column: I:I   --    matching with cell: X2

My current formula:

```
=INDEX('[Ship Log.xlsx]2023'!$F:$F,MATCH(1,(W12='[Ship Log.xlsx]2023'!$H:$H)*("*"&X12&"*"='[Ship Log.xlsx]2023'!$I:$I),0))
```

I like to believe I'm just using the function or some component the wrong way.

Comment: instead of `("*"&X12&"*"='[Ship Log.xlsx]2023'!$I:$I)` use `(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(X12,'[Ship Log.xlsx]2023'!$I:$I)))`

Comment: I don't think your present formula works in the same workbook as well, and I doubt about your statement saying it works, as in Excel wildcards dont work with an equal sign or any logical operators, yes it does works by using `SEARCH()` or `COUNTIFS()` or `SUMIFS()` or any supported functions, also as mentioned by @ScottCraner Sir. Can you post a screenshot showing that the present formula of yours is working, just wanted to know and gain some knowledge.